# Running a shell command

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm new to VBA access coding.

I'm trying to open a pdf in a particular location using shell command. Below are the line of codes i'm trying to execute.

```
VBA.Shell "Explorer.exe C:\Users\aulchala\Desktop\OIC.pdf", vbNormalFocus

VBA.Shell "Explorer.exe \\hyrrfs01\proj_hyrrin\Access\.pdf", vbNormalFocus
```

First line of code is executing and i'm able to open the right pdf.
Second line of code is executing. Instead of opening the right pdf it is navigating to some other folder.

I guess shell command is not working if the file location is not starting with "C:"

Comment: Are you aware that your 2nd example is also missing a filename? `\Access\.pdf"`

Answer (score 2):

It's working on mine so check your file path.

An alternative is to call the [Application.FollowHyperlink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.followhyperlink) method.

```
Sub OpenIt()
    Application.FollowHyperlink "\\hyrrfs01\proj_hyrrin\Access\.pdf"
End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work with UNC path also (at least is does on my computer).

Check path and name of the PDF file. If a folder is opened, you have probably provided an invalid path or file name. Have especially a look to what you wrote in your question, `.pdf` is probably not a valid file name.

Comment: Yes, the pdf file name is not there. If you want to open all pdf files in that folder, try `*.pdf`

Comment: I can confirm that .pdf is working even though it is not common.

Comment: @TWP: You mean `.pdf` as valid file name? Sure. What I ment is that OP probably has misspelled it in the code.